# Problem using OAuth2 with Discord API on NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to create a custom API for Discord but for now i'm trying to setup OAuth2.

To make the necessary HTTP Requests i'm using the included HttpModule in NestJS which is axios, so in my servisse i'm defining a function to retrieve the code (previously sent by Discord) and finally get the access token, here's how it looks:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

  async validateToken(token: string) {
    const data = {
      client_id: [some thing],
      client_secret: [some thing],
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: token,
      redirect_url: encodeURI('https://49fe5ab2.ngrok.io/auth'),
      scope: 'identify',
    };

    return await this.http
      .post('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', null, { params: data, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}})
      .toPromise()
      .then(resp => Logger.log(resp))
      .catch(err => Logger.error(err));
  }
}
```

And in the controller there's the route I set up for OAuth2 which is just a function

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly AuthService: AuthService) {}

  @Get()
  responseRetrieve(@Req() request) {
      return this.AuthService.validateToken(request.query.code);
  }
}
```

What happen is that I only get 401 status codes which means that all my access are unauthorized. I already tried to pass the data as the request body and finally as it's currently is as params.

OBS: I know that I should've used environment variables for client id and for the client_secret but for now i'm trying to make this work.

I'm not getting what i'm doing wrong because the only that does not work is the axios POST request right after I receive the code (also refered as token in the service function

Comment: Have you tested that the same callout does work from Postman or some other API tool? Also, any reason you're converting the Observable to a promise? I know it's possible, but any reason for it?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I converted it to Promise to be able to get some output of what might be happen since console.log or even Logger.log showed nothing. The problem is that either way it doesn't work. I don't really understand why do I get an 401 status since OAuth2 only gives the access token after a succesfull POST request which that I have nothing to put as Authorization which makes no sense to me

Comment: So is it Discord returning the `401`, or your Nest server? If it's the Nest server, it would seem you have an interceptor, or guard, or maybe middleware somewhere that's modifying the return code. That's my only guess as the `@Get()` decorator sets the return code to `200` on successful request. Did you try the request through and API tool like Postman?

Comment: Since the code parameter is dynamic an it's a value that's initally sent by Discord to be retrieved (POST) to receive the access token. I cannot make the test that request on Postman because it will never work and will always return "invalid_client" maybe because this request can only be made in the browser.

Comment: Riberio You could do the postman request in two steps, first making the callout to get the code that is returned by Discord and then making the similar call to what you are trying to debug at the moment. All the variables you are setting above are doable via Postman as well. Have you verified as well that the `@Get()` request has the expected value in it's `request.query.code`?